# Xcode Can't Recognize my ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

`SignUpViewController2` - I have already identified this in Xcode. Xcode says "use of undeclared type `SignUpViewController2`". I don't know why Xcode doesn't know what SignUpViewController2 is.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/b9bd7091467e71bb8ad5a73e840a1f9b.png]
[image]

Comment: you defined it as `SignUp2ViewController`in your identity inspector instead of `SignUpViewController2 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your identity inspector, under the "Class" attribute, you have it called "SignUp2ViewController", and you are programatically attempting to refer to it as "SignUpViewController2".